# Two examples side by side with expex

Tags: multicol, linguistics, examples, expex

I'm using expex for linguistic examples. Frequently, examples are very short and I would like to avoid wasting all that space by basically formatting the examples in the usual two columns way. However, with expex the example part labels are usually the wrong order if you do this using multicol.

a d

b e

c f

When I would obviously like them to be like this:

a b

c d

e f

Is there any good practice way to typeset two examples side by side using expex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use `\parbox`:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\parbox{.5\linewidth}{\pex aaa \xe}%
\parbox{.5\linewidth}{\pex bbb \xe}
\parbox{.5\linewidth}{\pex ccc \xe}%
\parbox{.5\linewidth}{\pex ddd \xe}
\parbox{.5\linewidth}{\pex eee \xe}%
\parbox{.5\linewidth}{\pex fff \xe}
\end{document}
```

If you use will use this a lot, consider simplify your life with a macro in the preamble like:

```
\newcommand\pexxe[1]{\parbox{.5\linewidth}{\pex #1 \xe}}
```

Then  simply use `\pexxe{aaa}\pexxe{bbb} ...` in the document

Comment: Don't forget to place a `%` (comment) character after instances 1, 2, and 5 of `\parbox{...}`.

Comment: @Mico In this case the extra space do not hurt, but good clearly better in this way.